# Regular Perturbation theory for $L=L_0+\epsilon ix$, where $L_0$ is an unbounded self-adjoint operator, on $\mathbb R$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, spectral-theory, perturbation-theory

I am looking to understand the spectrum of the following operator:
$L_{\epsilon}[u](x)=L_0[u](x)+i\epsilon x u(x)$ on $\mathbb R$. Here $L_0$ is a negative semi-definite self-adjoint operator that has a double zero eigenvalue, and all other eigenvalues are negative (& real).

**Q1:** Is this a well-studied problem ? Can I just use regular perturbation theory on this type of problem ?

Let $\lambda^0_i,v^0_i(x)$ be the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of $L_0$. Then can I expand
$\lambda^{\epsilon}_i=\lambda^0_i+\epsilon l_{i,1}+\epsilon^2 l_{i,2}+....$, and
$v^{\epsilon}(x)_i=v^0_i(x)+\epsilon v_{i,1}(x)+\epsilon^2 v_{i,2}(x)+....$, and proceed with regular perturbation theory ?

When I do as above, I find that the perturbation theory fails to accurately predict the imaginary part of the first couple of eigenvalues that are perturbations of the double zero eigenvalues.

**Q2:** Can we prove the above operator has a discrete spectrum ? In other words, can we prove that $R_{\lambda}=(\lambda-L_{\epsilon})^{-1}$ is a compact operator ?

Comment: There are some results for symmetric perturbations if the perturbation is "relatively bounded" with respect to the unperturbed. See Kato Rellich Theorem.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "regular perturbation theory". Does the derivation of the formulas you are using assume a symmetric perturbation (like $x$, not $ix$).